# populate the data in nodes using py2neo

Tags: python-3.x, graph, neo4j, py2neo

I've a JSON of the format

```
[
{
    "node": "Product",
    "properties": {
        "productId": [
            {
                "Data_Source": "hdfs:\/\/localhost:50070\/user\/",
                "Data_Set": "Employee",
                "Label_Field": "Employee_Age"
            }
        ],
        "unitPrice": [
            {
                "Data_Source": "hdfs:\/\/localhost:50070\/user\/",
                "Data_Set": "Employee",
                "Label_Field": "Employee_Age"
            }
        ],
        "unitsInstock": [
            {
                "Data_Source": "hdfs:\/\/localhost:50070\/user\/",
                "Data_Set": "Employee",
                "Label_Field": "Employee_DOB"
            }
        ],
        "unitsInorder": [
            {
                "Data_Source": "hdfs:\/\/localhost:50070\/user\/",
                "Data_Set": "Employee",
                "Label_Field": "Employee_Gender"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Relationships": [
        {
            "relation": "has",
            "destination": "Category"
        }
    ]
```

There can be any number of nodes in *JSON*. The data-set and label-field are *csv* data file and column being matched on that particular property of the node. When it comes to populating the graph, I'm traversing the data-set row-wise (consider there's only one *csv* for all).

```
const = 0
var = 5
```

while const < var:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    root_node = getNode(i)
    root_node = Node(root_node)
    print(root_node)
    prop = getProperties(i)
    print(prop)
    try:
        for j in range(len(prop)):
            name = prop[j]
            print(name)
            source = data[i]["properties"][name][0]['Data_Source']
            #getDataSource(i,j,prop[j])
            print(source)
            data_set = data[i]["properties"][name][0]['Data_Set']
            #getDataSet(i,j,prop[j])
            label_field = data[i]["properties"][name][0]['Label_Field']
            #getLabelField(i,j,prop[j])
            print(label_field)
            #df = pd.read_csv(source+data_set)
            root_node[name] = df[label_field][const]
            var = len(df.get(label_field))
graph.merge(root_node)
    except:
        pass
        r = getRelationships(i)
        try:
            for k in range(len(r)):
                relation = r[k].get("relation")
                print(relation)
                destination = r[k].get("destination")
                if destination in a:
                    m = a.index(destination)
                destination = Node(destination)
                print(destination)
                temp = getProperties(destination)
                try:
                    for l in range(len(temp)):
                        name = temp[l]
                        print(name)
                        source = data[m]["properties"][name][0]['Data_Source']
                        #source = getDataSource(m,l,temp[j])
                        print(source)
                        data_set = data[m]["properties"][name][0]['Data_Set']
                        #getDataSet(m,l,temp[j])
                        label_field = data[m]["properties"][name][0]['Label_Field']
                        #getLabelField(m,l,temp[j])
                        print(label_field)
                        #df = pd.read_csv(source+data_set)
                        destination[name] = df[label_field][const]
                    print(destination)
                    graph.merge(destination)
                    n = Relationship(root_node, relation, destination)
                    graph.create(n)
                except:
                    n = Relationship(root_node, relation, destination)
                    graph.create(n)
        except:
            pass           
const = const + 1
```

if there's any relation in that node, I've used another loop inside to build that node, and I'm merging nodes and relationships.

But I'm getting a non-connected graph. Can you suggest a better way to populate the graph or any suggestions in this will be appreciated?

Comment: Please improve readability by formatting the json code.

Comment: i've updated the question